# Is there any statistical measure/tool that compares two different sets of location configurations in R or ArcGIS/QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, r, spatial-analyst

Here is what I'd intend to do;

I have a given set of facility locations as shown below;

[image: Existing Network]

And based on a predefined one optimization criterion, I obtained the following configuration (and there are many other which resulted in different location configurations);

[image: Optimized Network]

I understand that whatever the optimization criterion I used, I can simply look at the criterion value for both and conclude that the optimized network is "better" (lower for minimization problem and higher for maximization problem). But I am in need of another statistical measure that will tell how similar the new network (i.e., 2nd figure) is when compared to the existing network (i.e., 1st figure). Below is the figure showing both configurations;

[image: Comparions]

There are several different optimized configurations obtained through utilizing different optimization criteria and the intent here is to quantitatively assess which optimization criterion would provide a solution (configuration that is most similar to the existing network.

I am thinking that calculating an average of shortest distance of all pairs could do the job but this may require some kind of a matching algorithm that I am not aware of.

Can anyone here suggest an existing package or tool that can do the job described above?

Answer (score 1):

I'd split the area into square polygons (size is a challenge), compute count of points per each scenario. Remove ones that have none in both, check correlation between counts.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Like you well pointed out, determining a "good" cell size could be a challenge as its output can differ significantly...

Comment: If they have common ID it is 10 mins job to make a script to calculate distance between pairs. Shall I?

Comment: I figured that the problem I am dealing with is heuristic so some type of meta-heuristic optimization algorithms are required to solve this problem. If there were IDs then it would be just a simple matching but it is not in this case... Thanks.